# How to remove columns with same value in R

Tags: r

**In short:**

I want to do this with my table,

[image]

**Explanation:**

I have big table with 20,000 x 1,200 items. I want to remove all the columns which have all the values same from top to bottom. But it shouldn't change the variable name(V2 in the example) so that later I can figure out which one them is removed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just use `vapply` to go through and check how many unique values there are in each column:

Sample data:

```
mydf <- data.frame(v1 = 1:4, v2 = 5:8,
                   v3 = 2, v4 = 9:12, v5 = 1)
mydf
##   v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
## 1  1  5  2  9  1
## 2  2  6  2 10  1
## 3  3  7  2 11  1
## 4  4  8  2 12  1
```

What we will be doing with `vapply`:

```
vapply(mydf, function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1, logical(1L))
#    v1    v2    v3    v4    v5 
#  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Keep the columns you want:

```
mydf[vapply(mydf, function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1, logical(1L))]
#   v1 v2 v4
# 1  1  5  9
# 2  2  6 10
# 3  3  7 11
# 4  4  8 12
```

Comment: @Dev, When you use `vapply` (as opposed to `sapply`), you have to specify the "template" that the output is expected to be in. In this case, we expect `length(unique(x)) > 1` to return either a single `TRUE` or a `FALSE`. Hence, our template is to expect a logical value of length 1, which we indicate with `logical(1L)` (`L` here represents an integer value).

Comment: @AnandaMahto Just coming across this post today. I learned more bout 'vapply' which I do not use often. By the way, I wanted to say thanks for your reply on git. I am using Mac and facing that `spread` issue quite a long time. Hope the issue will be solved in the future.

Comment: +1 This method works for both factors and numeric variables! I no longer have to worry about separating out the factors from the numeric columns before checking for multiple levels or variance = 0.

Answer (score 19):

In case someone tries to do this with `dplyr`, this yet another way to do it:

```r
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% select(where(~n_distinct(.) > 1))
```

Answer (score 12):

Here's a short way:

```
>Filter(var, mydf)
  v1 v2 v4
1  1  5  9
2  2  6 10
3  3  7 11
4  4  8 12
```

This works because a variance of zero is interpreted as false.

**Note:** doesn't work for character class columns.

Comment: This approach works only with numeric columns.  To be general, it may be `Filter(function(x) length(unique(x))>1, mydf)`

Comment: @akruIt will work for factors also, eg `var(PlantGrowth$group)`. It probably works for everything except characters.

Comment: @NealFuitz  Yes, but the `length(unique` will for most of the cases.

Answer (score 4):

Using `colSums`

```
df[colSums(df[1,][col(df)]!=df)!=0]
#  V1 V3 V4
#1  1  3  1
#2  4  4  2
#3  2  3  3
#4  5  3  3
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1, 4, 2, 5), V2 = c(2, 2, 2, 2), V3 = c(3, 
4, 3, 3), V4 = c(1, 2, 3, 3)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```